# "not A and B" vs "not A or B"

Tags: word-choice, idioms

- John is not good at both sports and studying.
- John is not good at either sports or studying.

Would there be any difference between the two?

Comment: The first means John is bad at *at least* one of them. The second means he's bad at both.

Comment: Could the first be interpreted the same as the second?

Comment: Yes it could. In fact, if the person speaking isn't a native speaker I will understand it to mean the second one.